# How can I keep keys in Ansible non recursively?

Tags: dictionary, ansible, key, ansible-filter

I want to remove some keys (nesting level 0) from a list of dictionnaries so that I can apply the `unique` filter and get some sort of classification of my list items. If I use the [ansible.utils.keep_keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html) filter, I get undesired results, because it only works recursively. This may result in kept unmatched keys on nesting level 0 if some subkey matches the filter. Further more, this filter behaves strangely if lists of integers are involved, e. g.:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list | keep_keys(target=['key0', 'key1']) | unique }}"
  vars:
    my_list:
      - key0: A
        key1: B
        key2:
          - 1
        key3: foo
      - key0: A
        key1: B
        key2:
          - 2
        key4: bar
```

results in:

```yaml
msg:
  - key0: A
    key1: B
    key2:
    - 1
  - key0: A
    key1: B
    key2:
    - 2
```

instead of:

```yaml
msg:
  - key0: A
    key1: B
```

`remove_keys` is not an option, because it also works recursively and the number of unwanted keys is way bigger than the number of desired keys. As `keep_keys` does not offer an option to work non recursively, I assume there must be another way to achieve this, but I cannot figure it out.

Is there a way to keep keys in Ansible non recursively, besides developing my own filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jinja. For example,

```yaml
  keep: [key0, key1]
  result: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in my_list %}
    - {{ dict(keep|zip(keep|map('extract', i))) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    - {key0: A, key1: B}
    - {key0: A, key1: B}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_list:
      - key0: A
        key1: B
        key2: [1]
        key3: foo
      - key0: A
        key1: B
        key2: [2]
        key4: bar

    keep: [key0, key1]
    result: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in my_list %}
      - {{ dict(keep|zip(keep|map('extract', i))) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: result|unique
```